# Prove that the Series $n^{-1}$ is Divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

How do you think of such proofs? Is there a more general strategy for solving such questions?

Comment: Do you mean $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1n \to \infty$$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's group the terms as follows:$$A=\frac11+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\cdots\\ $$
$$
A=\underbrace{(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{9})}_{\color{red} {9- terms}}
+\underbrace{(\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{12}+\cdots+\frac{1}{99})}_{\color{red} {90- terms}}\\+\underbrace{(\frac{1}{101}+\frac{1}{102}+\frac{1}{103}+\cdots+\frac{1}{999})}_{\color{red} {900- terms}}+\cdots \\ \to $$
$$\\A>9 \times(\frac{1}{10})+(90)\times \frac{1}{100}+(900)\times \frac{1}{1000}+... \\A>\frac{9}{10}+\frac{90}{100}+\frac{90}{100}+\frac{900}{1000}+...\\ \to A>\underbrace{\frac{9}{10}+\frac{9}{10}+\frac{9}{10}+\frac{9}{10}+\frac{9}{10}+\frac{9}{10}+...}_{\color{red} {\text{ m group} ,\text{  and} \space m\to \infty}} \to \infty
$$

Showing that $A$ diverges by grouping numbers.

Answer (score -1):

proof by contradiction

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n=\frac 1 1 + \frac 12 + \frac 13 + \cdots $$  I have seen many proofs of the result but recently found the following:
 $$S =\frac 1 1 + \frac 12 + \frac 13 +\frac 14+ \frac 15+ \frac 16+ \cdots$$
now $$1>\frac12 \to \text{ put } \frac12 \text{instead of } 1\\
\frac13>\frac14 \to \text{ put } \frac14 \text{instead of } \frac13\\
\frac15>\frac16 \to \text{ put } \frac16 \text{instead of } \frac15\\\vdots$$
 $$
S> \frac 12+\frac 12+ \frac 14+ \frac 14+ \frac 16+ \frac 16+ \cdots =\\(\frac 12+\frac 12)+ (\frac 14+ \frac 14)+ (\frac 16+ \frac 16)+ \cdots\\\frac 1 1 + \frac 12 + \frac 13 +\cdots = S.$$
In this way we see that $S > S$.

Answer (score -1):

$$-\ln(1-x)=x+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3+\frac{x^4}4+\dots\\x\to 1^-\\\lim_{x\to1^-}-\ln(1-x)=1+\frac{1^2}2+\frac{1^3}3+\frac{1^4}4+\dots$$ now let me to show 
$$x\to 1^- \to 1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+...=\frac{1}{1-x}\\so\\
\int (1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+...)dx=\int(\frac{1}{1-x})dx\\x+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3+\frac{x^4}4+\dots=-\ln(1-x)$$now let $x$ tends to $1^-$
$$\lim_{x\to1^-}-\ln(1-x)=1+\frac12+\frac{1}3+\frac14+\cdots\\-(-\infty)=1+\frac12+\frac{1}3+\frac14+\cdots$$
It is another idea